# Handle dynamic values on Oracle Apex from PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm currently using the Apex context to deploy a page created directly from PLSQL, I need to use the "Shared Components/Items" to store some dynamic values for the user and then be destroyed when the context is destroyed.

I'm using the Items but I couldn't find a way to create them dynamically from PLSQL so I'm looking for a replacement to this app behavior.

This is my current solution:

```
APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE (p_name    => 'Item_Name',
                                     p_value   => 'Item Value');
```

But this is not possible with dynamic Items or Variables,

What would you suggest?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: what do you mean when the context is destroyed?

Comment: "But this is not possible with dynamic Items or Variables" Ofc you can pass variables to procedure or function

Comment: Brenners1302: by context being destroyed I mean when the session expires.

Comment: Mladen: By dynamic Items I mean the parameters stored throughout the entire session and not handling variables just by procedure. I'm using collections, will post that later.

Comment: You terminology makes it difficult to comprehend the question.Collections appear to be the solution to your problem, but it's hard to tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this:

Collections

```
APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION(
p_collection_name IN VARCHAR2);

--and to add a value

Begin
APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBERS(
    p_collection_name => 'EMPLOYEE',
    p_c001 => l_arr1,
    p_c002 => 1_arr2);
End;
```

See documentation for more information:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_collection.htm#AEAPI531